# MVC route without controller or action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

Consider my route setting:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Question",
            url: "{number}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "ViewQuestion" }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { id = "\\d+" }
        );
    }
```

What I want is:

1) If a url like `myserver/123`, then call `Home.ViewQuestion(string number)`.

2) Otherwise, search in controllers and actions, with `Home/Index` default action

What I am getting now when requesting `myserver/123` is:

```
The view '123' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Home/123.aspx
~/Views/Home/123.ascx
~/Views/Shared/123.aspx
~/Views/Shared/123.ascx
~/Views/Home/123.cshtml
~/Views/Home/123.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/123.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/123.vbhtml
```

My Action and View:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace AdvancedWebApp.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult ViewQuestion(int? number)
        {
            return View(number + "");
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

ViewQuestion.cshtml:

```
@model string
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ViewQuestion";
}

<h2>ViewQuestion: @Model</h2>
```

Comment: Please make sure that your controller has action ViewQuestion. Also input parameter to method must name number. It is working for me locally as it is provided by you.

Comment: @dotnetstep I have created a new project, pasted the code into it and still not working.

Comment: Do you have any constraint for question route ? If yes then please check it is valid. http://imgur.com/sy94327 ( as per this image I see that constraint has some issue with value)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of url: "{number}" , use url: "ViewQuestion/{number}" and your action code:

```
public ActionResult ViewQuestion(int? number)
    {
        //your code
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I need to enter my website followed directly by number

Comment: ok then, there is one more way. in RouteConfig.cs , add this line routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); after the line routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");Then decorate your action method(ViewQuestion) with [Route("{number}")]

Comment: The route for eg. as you need -  http://localhost:8080/123 will call ViewQuestion action. It willl work. In the image you have upaloded i cannot see the url. If you follow the steps i have mentioned above, it will work. To avoid  calling controller helper method View(string viewName), you can keep it in a viewbag like ViewBag.QuestionNumber = questionNumber and in your view you can display it - @ViewBag.QuestionNumber  instead of passing (object)questionNumber from the View function.

Answer (score 1):

From your controller's action, it's seems like you are returning the view name as the number passed to it. So MVC runtime is looking for **123.html** or **123.aspx** while you have defined your view as ViewQuestion.cshtml.

```
public ActionResult ViewQuestion(int? number)
    {
        return View(number + "");
    }
```

You need to return the correct view name as following

```
public ActionResult ViewQuestion(int? number)
    {
        return View("ViewQuestion",number);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that I was calling controller helper method `View(string viewName)`, as if it is `View(object model)` !!!

```
    public ActionResult ViewQuestion(string questionNumber)
    {
        return View((object)questionNumber);
    }
```